# como evitar el registro de email duplicados PHP 7 - MYSQL-PDO

Tags: javascript, jquery, poo, pdo, php7

Ante todo buen día mis estimados, bueno tengo un pequeño problema al momento de desarrollar un sistema de registro ya que estoy usando `VMC` con `PHP7`, `MYSQL` .htaccess y PDO.

El problema es que no logro a evitar los **duplicados** de email al momento de realizar los registros en la DB por Views, cuando registros dos veces el mismo email me guarda normal a la DB por favor seria de mucho amable que me ayudaran a ver donde estoy cometiendo los errores o que es lo que me falta, aun soy nuevo en la **POO**.

Estos son mis codigos:

Mi Controlador:

```
<?php
 class Registro{


  public function RegistroController(){
  if(isset($_POST["saveRegistro"])){
    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nombre"])&&
       preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["email"])&&
       preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["password"])){

      $data = array("nombre"=>$_POST["nombre"],
                    "email"=>$_POST["email"],
                    "password"=>$_POST["password"]);

     $resp = RegistroModel::saveRegistroModel($data, "users");

         if($resp == "ok"){

            echo'El usuario fue registrado';
             }

         }
        else{
          echo $resp;
         }
      }
  }
```

Mi Modelo:

```
   <?php
require_once "modelo/conn.php";

class RegistroModel{

public function saveRegistroModel($dataModel, $tabla){

$conn = Conex::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (nombre, email, 
        password) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :password)");

$conn -> bindParam(":nombre", $dataModel["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$conn -> bindParam(":email", $dataModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$conn -> bindParam(":password", $dataModel["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

 if($conn->execute()){

        return "ok";
}

    else{

        return "error";
    }

    $conn->close();

}


public function buscarUsuarioDuplicado($dataModel, $tabla){

$conn = Conex::conectar()->prepare("SELECT email FROM $tabla WHERE 
             email = :email");

    $conn -> bindParam(":email", $dataModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($conn -> execute()){

        return "ok";

    }

    else{

        return "error";
    }

}
}
```

Mi Views:

```
        <h1>Registrarse</h1>
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
        <input name="saveRegistro" type="hidden" value="ok">            
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>

     <button id="enviar" type="submit"><span> Registrarme</span></button>
            <?php
                $saveRegistro = new Registro();
                $saveRegistro -> RegistroController();
            ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde mándas llamar `buscarUsuarioDuplicado`?

Comment: Si en la base de datos pones el campo email como unique?

Comment: Lo que Gabriel dice soluciona tu problema. Deberias añadir tambien la funcion trime () para que elimine los espacios que una persona pueda poner en el campo del mail.

Comment: Hola Gabriel Jeremy, si trato de poner unique al campo email se va solucionar el problema y que pasaría si intentan ingresar otra ves con el mismo email o  varias veces, ¿No guardaría a la DB el ultimo que fue ingresado?, para poder controlar eso no se necesita una condición, disculpa por mi ignorancia.